# Receiving FCM (GCM) behind proxy on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

We have an app that uses FCM (ex GCM) for push messaging and notification on Android devices.

We have an use case where the app won't have open access to Google Play Services as it will be deployed on a corporate network - well it is a "everything closed except fixed servers with fixed IP addresses and ports" firewall. Direct connection to these services will not be allowed, but we can provide our own http/s or socks proxy to access whatever we want.

To my latest knowledge and searches on SO, even if you specify a proxy on android, the proxy will only be used if your app is set up to use it (no problem), but Google Play Services and Firebase will just ignore the proxy setting.

Has this changed? Can Firebase/FCM/Google play services run through the proxy specified in Android? And if so, from which android version?

Thank you,
Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

Here is the latest info from the firebase support (short answer: no)

"
Unfortunately, Firebase Cloud Messaging is currently not designed to support a Proxy and does not attempt to address all network conditions. An alternative is to whitelist FCM to not go through a proxy at all. You should whitelist all of the IP addresses in the IPv4 and IPv6 blocks listed in Google's ASN of 15169. For more information regarding FCM ports, please refer to this documentation.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#ports_and_your_firewall
"

If any has ideas of workarounds, please feel free to share them :)
Thanks,
Nicolas